# Escribir resultados de consulta Sql server en fichero linea a linea

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un fichero en el cual tengo que insertar datos de una base de datos, tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada columna de la base de datos se corresponde con una fila la cual corresponde a un día, y cada -99999 se corresponde con una fila de la columna la cual corresponde a una media semihoraria(de 30 minutos), necesito ejecutar la consulta e insertar cada una de las filas de cada columna en el fichero sustituyendo a -99999,consigo insertar datos en la primera fila de la siguiente manera, pero, ¿como puedo avanzar a la segunda fila para insertar los de la segunda columna o como podría buscar la fila por fecha e insertar los datos en ella? El primer dato de cada fila lleva la fecha en formato MMyy en los 4 últimos números.

```
string query = @"select cochcorr, flag1, so2chcorr,flag2 from chimeneaCorregidos where Fecha >= DATEADD(Minute, -30, GETDATE())"; //consulta
string fileName = @"T19016098" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyy") +"horno1"+ ".dat";//nombre del fichero
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, CN);
        SqlDataReader leer;
        CN.Open();
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader(); //ejecuto el comando

        if (File.Exists(fileName)) //si el fichero existe
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write); //creo el file stream para abrirlo y escribir

            fs.Seek(22, SeekOrigin.Begin); //posiciono es stream en el byte 22 para empezar a escribir a continuación de la columna de identicficación            
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs); //creo el stream writer

            while (leer.Read()) {

               string datos  = leer[0].ToString().Trim() + leer[1].ToString().Trim()+" "; //obtengo los registros sql

                sw.Write(datos); //escribo los registros



            }

            CN.Close();
            sw.Close();
```

Esto me introduce los datos de la primera columna y la segunda(los cuales deben estar juntos puesto que el segundo es un validador del dato) pero ahora necesito insertar los de la tercera columna y cuarta en la segunda linea y así con mas registros sucesivamente.Gracias, estoy un poco perdido con el tema de los ficheros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La confusion que leo entre columnas y filas me desconcierta mucho mas.. Tu problema es recorrer el archivo? olvidate de la db, lo primero que hay que lograr es recorrer y separar datos no?

Comment: Si, efectivamente, recorrer el archivo por palabras y por filas, cómo puedo hacerlo? Lo ideal sería si hay algún método para recorrerlo mediante un array bidimensional por filas y palabras , por qué mediante bytes no puedo recorrerlo por qué no siempre van a tener el mismo tamaño las palabras

Comment: fijate de abrirlo como un textreader, es mucho mas simple..

Comment: pero y como puedo identificar cada palabra de una fila con textreader?

Comment: Supongo que estan separadas de alguna forma no? Entonces vas a poder encontrar cada una.